# Cannot set developer mode on Magento using docker

Tags: developer-mode, deploy

I'm running the command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set: developer` inside a docker container.

It's outputting the same error below for many files.

```
The "/var/www/html/var/cache/mage--7/mage---792_MAGE_VERSION" file can't be deleted. Warning!unlink(/var/www/html/var/cache/mage--7/mage---792_MAGE_VERSION): Permission denied
```

What I tried:

- chmod -R 777 var/cache (outputs error `operation not permitted`)

Comment: change permission for var pub and generated.
Sudo chmod -R 777 var pub generated

Comment: permission with super user.
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub generated.

Comment: When I try to log as super user using `su -`  it asks for a password. Is there a default?

Comment: yes it is default password. for your syste,

Comment: instead of su -
Use command with sudo.
Ex sudo chmod -R 777 var pub generated

Comment: Do I have to install sudo command? When I try to run it outputs `sudo command not found`.

Comment: Are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Linux Debian 5.10. I connect via Remote SSH in VS Code.

Comment: apt install sudo

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/sudo-command-in-linux/

Comment: I installed `sudo` as you said. After that I had the error `The "env.php" deployment config file isn't writable.` Then I added write permission to that file using `WinSCP`. Developer mode enabled. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply proper permission to **pub** **var** and **generated** folder.

execute below command.

> sudo chmod -R 777 var pub generated